# How to Disable welcome message in header file in magento 2?

Tags: magento2.3, header

How to disable Welcome message in magento 2.3

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to

> **magento2/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml**

and remove the `<li>` tag marked in the picture below.

[image]

If using any custom theme, you may find the relevant file in app/design/theme directory and modify code in that file.

**Run upgrade and cache commands, and you're good to go.**

Also you can remove the message from admin panel as shown from below location:

[image]

But, this will still display the username if customer is loggedin.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**
If you want to disable welcome message only for the guest user:

> Admin sidebar > Content > Design > Configuration > EDIT current
> theme(Store View) > Header > Welcome Text(Remove text)

**Option 2:**
To keep the header intact and just hide the welcome message:

> <your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="header">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="show_part" xsi:type="string">other</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>        
    </body>
</page>
```

**Option 3:** To completely remove the header.phtml

> <your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="top.links">
            <referenceBlock name="header" remove="true"/>  
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Option 4:** To customize structure based on requirement, override header.phtml file into your theme folder. Copy file from the following path and put into your theme folder:

From:

> vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml

To:

> <your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml

**Note:** To create a storefront theme, refer to the [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html)

Comment: Hi Pratik. I am using custom theme and want to remove only welcome admin. Please ket me know which option i can use?

Comment: So you want to remove welcome message for both Guest and Login user right?

Comment: Yes, for both user

Comment: You can implement "Option 2" OR "Option 4"

Comment: I tried Option 2 but not working.

Comment: Then you can try Option 4